# mainloop overides while loop in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Everything works but the time does not update and I think it is because the mainloop overrides the while loop. Please help, I have searched for a long time and found nothing.

While loop is below then main code:

```
def loop1():
    Time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    while Time != Alarm:
        Time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        alarm = Tk()
        label3 = Label(alarm, text=Time)
        label3.grid(column=0, row=0)
        alarm.mainloop()
        #Get new time
        Time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        #Change to next second
        label3.config(text=Time)
```

Main code:

```
#Import libraries
from tkinter import *
import time

Time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

def loop1():
    Time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    while Time != Alarm:
        Time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        alarm = Tk()
        label3 = Label(alarm, text=Time)
        label3.grid(column=0, row=0)
        alarm.mainloop()
        #Get new time
        Time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        #Change to next second
        label3.config(text=Time)

initalarm = Tk()
label1 = Label(initalarm,text="What time do you want to wake up?")
label2 = Label(initalarm,text="Use this form.\nExample: 06:30:00")
Alarm = Entry()
start = Button(initalarm, text="Set Alarm", command=loop1)
label1.pack()
label2.pack()
Alarm.pack()
start.pack()
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How to make it work

Comment: Please answer with block changed or all changed.:(

Comment: Make _what_ work?

Comment: To make the label update

Comment: because when the mainloop overrides the while loop it won't continue so doesn't update

Comment: Your code has multiple mistakes, and bad practices.

Comment: `Time != Alarm` is never `False`, makes the loop a `While True` which is not exactly okay with a tkinter GUI.

Comment: What I'm saying is while it is true that `alarm.mainloop()` overrides in the very first time it is read in the what essentially is `While True` loop, even if `alarm = Tk()` didn't exist, which it shouldn't, you would still not be getting the behavior you want.

Answer (score 3):

`mainloop` doesn't *override* anything. It simply will not return until the root window is destroyed. Or more correctly, it won't return until `root.quit()` is called, which happens automatically when the root window is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't fight against the framework, use it.  GUI programming with Tk is event driven, i.e. you don't control the control flow of your program directly in long running loops.  Instead you set up handlers for different events which get called from Tk's main loop when the events occur.  Examples of events are button presses or when a certain given time has passed.  This can be used to regularly get some handler called by the main loop for updating the display and eventually activating the alarm.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import nametofont
from tkinter.simpledialog import askstring
from datetime import datetime as DateTime


def update_display(time_label, alarm_time):
    now = DateTime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    if now >= alarm_time:
        time_label['foreground'] = 'yellow'
    time_label['text'] = now
    time_label.after(500, update_display, time_label, alarm_time)


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Alarm Clock')

    font = nametofont('TkTextFont').copy()
    font['size'] *= 5

    time_label = tk.Label(root, text='--:--:--', font=font)
    time_label.pack()

    alarm_time = askstring(
        'When?', 'What time do you want to wake up?\nExample: 06:30:00'
    )
    if alarm_time is not None:
        update_display(time_label, alarm_time)
        root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The code does approximately what was tried with the code in the question if I got it right, but an actual useful alarm clock program needs object oriented programming in Python, if it should not become a hard to understand and follow mess.

Also I would not operate on the times as strings but as objects from the `datetime` module, or at least as number of seconds since ”epoch” with the `time` module.  The string form is better left to input and output for the user.  And the user input should be validated.  In the current form it is too easy to enter invalid alarm times by accident.

Comment: `.after()` is super buggy

Comment: @Hippolippo No it is not.  That's the way and that's how all Tk (not only Tkinter/Python programs) do this kind of stuff for *decades*.  I guess someone would have already noticed if it is ”super buggy”.  It's `update()` that is not buggy but can be dangerous if you don't know exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding you are looking for the label to be updated till it reaches alarm time. If that's true than there are two thing wrong with your code

1. alarm = Tk() should be moved out of the while loop
2. You should use alarm.update() instead of alarm.mainloop()

> Updated loop1 definition:

```
def loop1():
    Time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    alarm = Tk()
    while Time != Alarm:
        Time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        label3 = Label(alarm, text=Time)
        label3.grid(column=0, row=0)
        alarm.update()
        #Get new time
        Time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        #Change to next second
        label3.config(text=Time)
```

> Main code:

```
#Import libraries
from tkinter import *
import time

Time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

def loop1():
    Time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    alarm = Tk()
    while Time != Alarm:
        Time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        label3 = Label(alarm, text=Time)
        label3.grid(column=0, row=0)
        alarm.update()
        #Get new time
        Time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        #Change to next second
        label3.config(text=Time)

initalarm = Tk()
label1 = Label(initalarm,text="What time do you want to wake up?")
label2 = Label(initalarm,text="Use this form.\nExample: 06:30:00")
Alarm = Entry()
start = Button(initalarm, text="Set Alarm", command=loop1)
label1.pack()
label2.pack()
Alarm.pack()
start.pack()
```

Comment: Having more than one `Tk` instance is wrong. This may appear to work, but it may also fail in subtle or spectacular ways.

Answer (score -1):

The way that `root.mainloop()` or in your case `alarm.mainloop()` works is that it will make it's own loop that will update the root (or alarm) window. Whenever a command is run (like a root.bind, or a button command) it will pause the mainloop
Because mainloop is looping, doing it's own thing, it will never reach lines past the `root.mainloop()` or `alarm.mainloop()` (unless some weird errors occur).
A really easy way to fix that is to make your own "mainloop" by having a loop that does your things and then uses `root.update()` or `alarm.update()` (which is what is being run over and over by the mainloop command but you can "customize" the loop)

Using this will still allow the binds and button commands to work. Instead of calling `alarm.mainloop()` before your loop, call `alarm.update()` inside of your loop

Comment: Instead of using `update()` with the problems that may come with it, it would be better not to try to work against the framework.  Let the `mainloop()` call a method on a regular basis instead of trying to reinvent the main loop.

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: See my answer. :-)